# UI size changes when switching to a different device

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

So I am quite new to Unity Development, and I have run into a problem. I have two UI's in my game (two buttons), however, when I change the device from an Iphone 12 (landscape) to a Iphone 11 (landscape), the UI's ratio goes all whacky and it changes size. Is there any way I can prevent this? I will link photos below

So this is what it looks like if the camera is in the Iphone 12 landscape 'mode'
[image]

and this is what it looks like in Iphone 11 'mode'

[image]

The ratio and size of the UI goes all whacky. How do I fix this?

(a picture of my canvas inspector

[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture of your canvas inspector?

Comment: Try to go on player settings (Boot settings / player settings) and try to find max resolution and set the resolution of your camera.

Comment: sure. I just posted it in the question

Answer (score 1):

One thing that comes to mind is to change the [Canvas Scaler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-CanvasScaler.html)s `UI Scale Mode` from "Constant Pixel Size" to one of the other options, depending on what works best for you.

Unfortunately, "Constant Pixel Size" is the default value and it usually breaks everything when building a full screen UI.

Answer (score 1):

For canvas settings, use the "**scale with screen size**" option and play around with the values. If most of the resolutions look fine but there is a spesific one that straight up breaks your UI, you can write a script to check if its that resolution and change the canvas values.

[image]

For UI elements you can play around with the setting I circled in red. [image]

Also you might want to check [this thread.](https://forum.unity.com/threads/canvas-scaler-scale-with-screen-size-same-as-setting-ui-objects-to-stretch.512005/)